# Integrate $\int\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I go about integrating:

$$\int\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

The common trigonometric substitutions don't seem to work here.

I think it requires to take some power of $x$ outside the square root but I am not able to solve further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT....If you want a trig substitution that works, try $x^2=\cos 2\theta$

Comment: Works very well !!

Comment: $$\int\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{\frac {1-x^2}{1+x^2}}dx= \int\frac{1}{x^2}\sqrt{\frac {1-\cos 2t}{1+\cos 2t}}(-\sin2t)dt$$

$$=\int\frac{1}{\cos2t}\cdot\tan t \cdot(-\sin2t)dt=-\int \tan 2t \cdot\tan t dt$$ Then what ?

Comment: write $\tan 2t\tan t$ in terms of sin and cos, and get $\frac{2\sin^2t}{\cos 2t}$ and then use $2\sin^2t=1-\cos 2t$'and then you're pretty much home and dry.

Answer (score 7):

**The answer is (after a request from OP) updated with more details**

I suggest you to set
$$
u=\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}.
$$
Then
$$
x^2=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}
$$
and so
$$
2x\,dx=-\frac{4u}{(1+u^2)^2}\,du.
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{1}{x}\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}\,dx&=\int\frac{1}{2x^2}\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}\,2x\,dx\\
&=\int\frac{1}{2}\frac{1+u^2}{1-u^2}u\cdot\Bigl(-\frac{4u}{(1+u^2)^2}\Bigr)\,du\\
&=-\int\frac{2u^2}{(1-u^2)(1+u^2)}\,du.
\end{aligned}
$$
Next, do a partial fraction decomposition, and you will end up with
$$
\int\frac{1}{1+u^2}\,du-\int\frac{1}{1-u^2}\,du.
$$
I guess you can take it from here? If not, ask for more details.

Comment: I can do the latter .. However how did u simplified it ?? Because I am trying the same using that substitution and it looks messy..

Comment: Got it Thanks..